# opencart layout and position issue

Tags: opencart

i have installed opencart 1.5.6 with oxy theme and im having a strange problem with the layouts..

i want to show the slider and the latest products in the homepage and in the layout i have selected "home" which routes to common/home

but the problem is when i go to all the inner pages the slider and the latest products are still visible

and secondly im having a problem with the left column and right column. im have set the category links on the left column and layout category but they are not visible.

can someone tell what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

- If there are multiple same route has been added then this problem
  will happened.Go to admin -> system then go the Design->layouts and
  check the other layout routes.If any other page have the same
  'common/home' route remove it. I think then your first problem will
  be solved.

Check the category template whether there is $column_left,
 `$column_right` is present or not if not then echo it here. After that check it once.